# Include 3rd-party Mango/slideout to angular-cli project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm struggling to add [slideout](https://github.com/Mango/slideout) to my angular 2 application. Tried to follow this guide [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs#adding-underscore-library-to-your-project).

So what I have done is, installed npm package:

```
npm install slideout --save
```

Installed typings:

```
typings install dt~slideout --global --save
```

Added slideout to angular-cli-build.js:

```
var Angular2App = require('angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      ...,
      'slideout/dist/slideout.js'
    ]
  });
};
```

Added slideout to system-config.ts:

```
/** Map relative paths to URLs. */
const map: any = {
  'slideout': 'vendor/slideout/dist/slideout.js'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'slideout': {
    format: 'cjs'
  }
};
```

When I try to use it insid a component within Visual Studio Code it I get an error saying `[ts] Cannot find module 'slideout'.`.

Trying to build with `ng build` produces the same error `Cannot find module 'slideout'.`

**Versions**

```
angular: 2.0.0-rc.2
slideout: 0.1.12
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.6
```

What am I doing wrong/missing? Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you do anything with your `map` constant?

Comment: Like `var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);`

Comment: Yes, at the end of system-config.ts I have `System.config({ map, packages });`

Comment: The error you get is in design-time in VS Code. So, its related to tsc. Since tsc cannot find definition file for your new import its giving off this error. Try installing a definition file for this library. search `typings`.

Comment: I know it's tsc, if you look at what I wrote you see that I installed typings.